# Using HTML5 Data Attribute in jQuery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Noob Question on Data Attribute

I was wondering will using data-attribute in jQuery Selector can bring any trouble in the future?

I'm trying to reduced the usage of .class and #id as jQuery Selector, since most of data I'm working on will generated from data-attribute

example of the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var mydata = $(document).data('my-data-attribute');

});
```

will the code above slowing the load time?

or

```
$('[data-suffix-attribute="some_value"]').each(function(){
   ......
});
```

or

```
$('[data-suffix-attribute="delete"]').click(function(){
   // delete action happening here
});
```

will this bring trouble?

Comment: wont do trouble but selecting IDs is the fastest and most reliant to go. also, dont mix data-attribute and jquery's .data() function

Comment: also, the .data() function in jQuery uses an internal system for storing variables, it just also reads the `data-` attributes to populate that, so if you were to do this `$('#hello').data('hello', 'world');` and then tried to access the data attribute `data-hello` there wouldn't be a value defined, or if you did define it, that value would not change and jQuery would always use it's internal value after initialization.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob in javascript, but I search on google and the way to grab data attribute is using .data() function, Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var mydata = $(document).data('my-data-attribute');

});
```

The code above will not work. If you want to read the HTML5 data attribute of an element using the jQuery .data() method firstly you need to select the relevant element using a jQuery selector and then you can use the method as is shown below:

```
var mydata = $('.example').data('suffix');
```

This will read the value of the data-suffix attribute of an element with a class of "example".

The other important thing to note when using the .data() method is that you have to omit the data- prefix from the selector to read the value stored in that attribute.

The way you have selected the attribute before the .each() method will work:

```
$('[data-suffix-attribute="some_value"]');
```

However, it would be better if you can narrow it down to a specific element like:

```
$('div[data-suffix-attribute="some_value"]');
```

This is because the first selector will go through every node in the document which will take more time whereas the second will only go through the div tags in the document.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :D, it looks like the best way is to use the narrowed down selector :D

Answer (score 0):

The attribute selector is supported by the native query selectors so it is fine. As far as future is concerned I don't think in near future it will be a problem.

But it will be better if you can use a element selector attached to the attribute selector like `$('div[data-suffix-attribute="delete"]')`

If you are very worried about performance it will be a better choice to add a class attribute to the desired elements and then use class selector

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use `id` in `selector` which is `fast` obviously,
If you have `multiple data attributes` then it is better to use `$('[data-suffix-attribute="delete"]').click();`.
Instead of this you can use the `parent selector` for your `data-attribute elements` like,

```
$('#parentId').on('click','[data-suffix-attribute="delete"]',function(){
   // delete action happening here
});
```

`#parentId` contains all `data attribute elements`